# What is the equivalent in VB.NET for a thread delegate?

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-4.0

I am trying to convert the C# code from this Stack Overflow question to be used in VB.NET.  I am using .NET Framework 4.0.
[WPF wait window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369853/wpf-wait-window)

Here is the code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
      Window1 w = new Window1();
      w.Show();

      w.Closed += (sender2, e2) =>
      w.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();

      System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    });

thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

Comment: The problem is obvious. 6th word in the title :)

Comment: LOL, I wish I was back doing C#.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim thread As New Thread(Sub()
    Dim w As New Window1()
    w.Show()
    AddHandler w.Closed, Sub(sender2, e2) w.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown()
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
End Sub)

thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
thread.Start()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a lambda expression in VB, like this:

```vb
Dim thread As New Thread(Sub()
                             ' ...
                         End Sub)
```

VB.NET doesn't really have a separate syntax for anonymous methods, like C# does, but the syntax for a lambda expression in VB.NET looks more similar to a C# anonymous method than to a C# lambda expression.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to read [Lambda Expressions in VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx)

```
Dim threadSub = Sub()
                  ...
                End Sub
Dim thread As New Thread(threadSub)
```